# React Navigation (Native) - Typescript Composite Screen Props - Navigation set to any

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

**Goal:** Trying to set types on `navigation` for a Tab screen navigating to a child Stack screen

**Navigator Structure**: `TabNavigator` parent that renders a `StackNavigator`

```
  const HomeStackScreen = () => (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
          <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <HomeStack.Screen name="Person" component={PersonScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="HomeStack" component={HomeStackScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="AddPerson" component={AddPersonScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
```

**Problem:** When using `CompositeScreenProps`, the `route` prop is typed but `navigator` prop isn't.

[composite type helper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uNJA.png)

[navigation has any type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNaoo.png)

**Questions:**

1. Why is the route typed but `navigation` not?
2. Is it ok to render a Tab as parent to Stack?
3. How do I get the `navigation` to be typed?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had similar issue, try not to import person type just implement it inside homeStackParamList in Person key. For some reason compositeScreenProps is not working well with external types